# jQuery validate não funciona em modal

Tags: jquery, modal, jquery-validate

Tenho uma modal com um formulário. Usei esse plugin para criar a modal: 
https://github.com/samdark/the-modal

Uso também o jquery validate.

Ele funciona em todos os formulários do meu site. Porém no formulário que está dentro da minha modal ele não funciona.

Alguém tem alguma ideia?

HTML:

```
        <form id="form-contato" action="enviar.php" method="post">

            <h5>Deixe sua mensagem</h5>

            <input type="hidden" name="field-home">

            <div>
                <label>Nome <span>*</span></label><br>
                <input type="text" name="nome_completo" class="input-full" required="true">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>E-mail <span>*</span></label><br>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="input-full" required="true">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Telefone</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="telefone" class="input-half">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Assunto </label><br>
                <input type="text" name="assunto" class="input-full">
            </div>

            <div>
                <label>Mensagem <span>*</span></label>
                <textarea name="mensagem" class="input-textarea" required="true"></textarea>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="enviar">
                Enviar <i class="fa fa-paper-plane" aria-hidden="true" style="margin-left: 5px;"></i>
            </button>
```

```
<script>
$("#form-contato").validate({
            rules : {
                nome_completo: {
                    required:true
                },
                email: {
                    required:true,
                    email:true
                },
                mensagem: {
                    required:true
                }
            },
            messages:{
                nome_completo: {
                    required: "Campo obrigatório."
                },
                email:{
                    required: "Campo obrigatório.",
                    email: "Informe um e-mail válido."
                },
                mensagem: {
                    required: "Campo obrigatório."
                }
            }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Gera algum erro no console? Poste um pedaço do código que seja relevante para que possamos analisar.

Comment: Não gera nenhum erro no console. Colocado o HTML e a validação do jquery validate.

Comment: Creio que isso esteja acontecendo porque você esta validando um form oculto, chame isso `$("#form-contato").validate({` depois de abrir o modal.

Comment: Bom dia. Consegui resolver. Obrigado.